# startActivity method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,Game.class);
intent.putExtra("razmer", level);
startActivity(intent);
```

method startActivity() call constuctor class.This method creat object this class?send me more detail about this method please

Comment: Can you be MORE clear about your question ? What problem are you facing exactly ?

Comment: I think you are finding way to use constructor of activity... but it would be better to tell why you are looking for that we may suggest any option for that base problem ....

Comment: I created object of the class Game and after  I created Intent to start activity of this class, the constructor of the class Game call 2 times. And it is necessary for me that I created object, created Intent for activity start, and that thus the constructor call once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah dude the method startActivity() is used for launching another activity whichever class you call in the intent.Understand but it wont call the constructor class.And moreover the Activity Manager will instantiates an activity object.

Answer (score 1):

StartActivity method notify android system to launch a new activity, ActivityManager instantiate An Activity Object, and then Launch the Activity.